# How to remove pipelines from ADF?

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

Whenever I try to delete any pipeline from ADF, I get following error message:

```
The scope '/subscriptions/<subscription_id>/resourcegroups/<RGName>/providers/Microsoft.DataFactory/datafactories/<ADF_Name>/datapipelines/HivePipe' 
cannot perform delete operation 
because following scope(s) are locked: '/subscriptions/<subscription_id>/resourceGroups/<Name of Resource Group>'. 
Please remove the lock and try again.
```

Can anyone guide me on how to delete unwanted pipelines using Azure portal?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. Open your Azure Data Factory Blade
2. Click "Author and Deploy"
   [image]
3. Expand Pipelines node
4. Right click and "Delete" the pipeline

[image]

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

It's much easier and faster to delete them using powershell. If you have dozens of pipelines, it takes lot of time to do it from the UI:-

[Powershell remove pipeline reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/mt603653.aspx)

Comment: Here's a better link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azurerm.datafactories/remove-azurermdatafactorypipeline?view=azurermps-4.3.1